# Too many redirects mobile version only

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, redirect

having a odd issue site is throwing error when i use google inspector mobile version it states  redirected you too many times. try clearing your cookies

not sure whats going on its a multi store setup http://coyoteperformanceparts.com

I have tried reindexing and here my .htaccess

#

### uncomment these lines for CGI mode

### make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name

### it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

## Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi

## AddHandler php5-cgi .php

#

### GoDaddy specific options

## Options -MultiViews

### you might also need to add this line to php.ini

### cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1

### if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

#

### this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

```
#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

#

### default index file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

#

### adjust memory limit

## #php_value memory_limit 64M

```
php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

#

### disable magic quotes for php request vars

```
#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

#

### disable automatic session start

### before autoload was initialized

```
#php_flag session.auto_start off
```

#

### enable resulting html compression

```
##php_flag zlib.output_compression on
```

#

## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

```
#php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
```

#

## turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

```
#php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
```

#

## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

#

### enable apache served files compression

### http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

```
# Insert filter on all content
###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
#BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
#Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

#

### make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

```
SSLOptions StdEnvVars
```

#

### enable rewrites

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

#

### you can put here your magento root folder

### path relative to web root

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

#

### uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

## RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

#

### rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

```
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

#

### workaround for HTTP authorization

### in CGI environment

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

#

### TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

#

### redirect for mobile user agents

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
```

#

### always send 404 on missing files in these folders

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
```

#

### never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

#

### rewrite everything else to index.php

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

#

### Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides

### If you still have problems, use the second line instead

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

#

### Add default Expires header

### http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
```

#

### By default allow all access

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

#

### Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

```
<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

#

### If running in cluster environment, uncomment this

### http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

```
#FileETag none
```

order allow,deny
allow from all

deny from 71.99.54.121
deny from 96.252.247.182
deny from 96.92.0.1

### EXPIRES CACHING

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding

Header set Cache-Control "max-age=300"
 Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding

# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent

ExpiresActive On
     ############################################
     ## Add default Expires header
     ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
     
     ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

## Set XSS Protection header

Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

## Enable expirations

ExpiresActive On

## HTML

ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"

## Enable expirations

ExpiresActive On

## My favicon

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

## Images

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

## Enable expirations

ExpiresActive On

## Javascript

ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

## Enable expirations

ExpiresActive On

## CSS

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"

## Enable expirations

ExpiresActive On

## HTML

ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"

ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 31 Aug 2009 00:00:00 GMT"

SetEnvIf Host www.coyoteperformanceparts.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=coyoteperformanceparts
SetEnvIf Host www.coyoteperformanceparts.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^coyoteperformanceparts.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=coyoteperformanceparts
SetEnvIf Host ^coyoteperformanceparts.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www.4everlighting.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=foureverlighting
SetEnvIf Host www.4everlighting.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^4everlighting.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=foureverlighting
SetEnvIf Host ^4everlighting.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www.mightystarter.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=mightystarter
SetEnvIf Host www.mightystarter.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^mightystarter.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=mightystarter
SetEnvIf Host ^mightystarter.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

## php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

## Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.

AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml

## php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

Comment: in addition per the tutorials on the multi store setup my main index.php includes /* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

Comment: and each store for examople has a copy of index.php with tailored code  /* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run('coyoteperformanceparts','website');